# Como filtra uma lista com varias palavras em python?

Tags: python, filtro

Como posso fazer um filtro em uma lista da mesma forma que posso fazer em SQL?

Ex: No SQL eu consigo fazer vários AND em um campo de texto com o CHARINDEX

```
SELECT * FROM TB_Produto AS A (NOLOCK) 
WHERE CHARINDEX('papel', NM_PRODUTO) > 0
AND CHARINDEX('sulfite', NM_PRODUTO) > 0
```

Gostaria de fazer a mesma coisa em python, até cheguei a fazer o filtro

```
results = [t for t in buscaproduto if t.NM_PRODUTO.find(termo) > -1]
```

Mas meu ***termo*** passado tem a palavra inteira (papel sulfite).

A ideia é que se eu não acha a palavra **papel sulfite** eu faça uma nova busca só por **papel**, por isso queria uma forma de filtra as palavras separadas e que cada palavra estivesse em qualquer parte da string da minha coluna.

Comment: Por que não escreve uma função `busca_termo(termo, texto) -> bool` que faz todas as validações que precisa e na expressão faz `[t for t in buscaprodutos if busca_termo(termo, t.NM_PRODUTO)]`. Se a sua função retornar True, o elemento estará na lista final.

Comment: @Woss, sabe como quebra a string em partes e fazer tipo if texto.find(papel'') and if texto.find('sulfite') dinamicamente ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pela sua descrição ("*se eu não achar a palavra papel sulfite eu faça uma nova busca só por papel*"), daria para fazer assim:

```
def busca_termo(termo, texto):
    # primeiro vê se o termo está contido no texto
    if termo in texto:
        return True
    # senão, procura apenas pela primeira palavra do termo dentro do texto
    return termo.split(maxsplit=1)[0] in texto

produtos = ['papel A4', 'caderno', 'papel sulfite', 'sulfite']
termo = 'papel sulfite'

results = [ p for p in produtos if busca_termo(termo, p) ]
print(results) # ['papel A4', 'papel sulfite']
```

Como você está usando `find`, entendi que o termo pode estar em qualquer posição da string (ou seja, `termo` deve ser uma substring de `texto`). Como você não parece precisar do índice (e só quer saber se é substring ou não), [a própria documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) recomenda usar o operador `in` em vez de `find`.

No exemplo acima, se o termo for "papel sulfite", primeiro eu verifico se todo o termo está contido no texto. Senão, eu procuro apenas se "papel" está contido no texto.

---

Entendi que não precisa fazer a busca por "sulfite", mas caso queira buscar por todas as palavras do termo, basta mudar a função `busca_termo` para:

```
def busca_termo(termo, texto):
    # primeiro vê se o termo está contido no texto
    if termo in texto:
        return True
    # verifca se tem alguma palavra do termo que está contida no texto
    return any(palavra for palavra in termo.split() if palavra in texto)

produtos = ['papel A4', 'caderno', 'papel sulfite', 'sulfite']
termo = 'papel sulfite'

results = [ p for p in produtos if busca_termo(termo, p) ]
print(results) # ['papel A4', 'papel sulfite', 'sulfite']
```

Agora ele busca primeiro por "papel sulfite", e se não encontrar, procura separadamente por "papel" e "sulfite" (retornando `True` se encontrar qualquer um deles).

Comment: acho que sua segunda função é o que estava querendo, vou testa aqui, está bem mais simplificado do que a que eu fiz.

Answer (score 0):

Com a ideia do @Woss, montei uma função recursiva que verificar se existe as palavras na string e se já encontrou todas as palavras alguma vez antes.

```
def filtra_busca_termo(termo, termoBusca, achouTermo):
    achou = False
    palavras = termo.split()
    for palavra in palavras:
        if termoBusca.find(palavra) != -1:
            achou = True
        elif achouTermo:
            return False
        elif termo != ' ' and len(palavras) > 1:
            termo = termo.rsplit(' ', 1)[0]
            return filtra_busca_termo(termo, termoBusca, achouTermo)

    return achou
```

Assim chamo ela o monto uma nova lista filtrada

```
produtosFiltro = []
achouTermo: bool = False
for produto in buscaproduto:
    termo = termo.lower()
    termoBusca = produto.TermoBusca.lower()
    if filtra_busca_termo(termo, termoBusca, achouTermo):
        produtosFiltro.append(produto)
```